# How to skip to end of parenthesis in Xcode

Tags: xcode

After I'm done typing the parameters inside a set of parenthesis, how to skip the cursor to behind the parenthesis so I can just press the semicolon to finish it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>right arrow</kbd> will take you to the end of line.

Comment: Can you change this? I'm used to pressing Tab in Aptana

Comment: Yes. In the Xcode Menu, select Preferences. Then "Key Bindings", then "Text". Look for row that says, "Move to Right End of Line" and then change from default setting (command right-arrow) to anything you like.